# How to stop axios sending the cookie in every request withCredentials false

Tags: vue.js, axios

When I am making a request, axios is attaching the whole cookie along with it.

I have already tried

```
withCredentials: false
```

And

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = false;
```

Still its sending the cookies...

This is where I am creating the request..

```
import axios from 'axios'

// create an axios instance
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api/v1/', // url = base url + request url
  withCredentials: false, // send cookies when cross-domain requests
  timeout: 5000 // request timeout
})
```

Its still sending the cookie with it

Please help

Comment: The browser adds cookies automatically, not axios. Is this a cross-origin request or a same-origin request? It might help if you could explain why you're setting a cookie in the first place if you don't want to send it on the request.

Comment: Its same origin request, I am storing the auth token, and other logged in user info in the cookie...

But I want to send only the token as Authorization, not the whole cookie, 

Surprisingly, I have another project, where this does not happen,,

Comment: Same problem here with the same origin request.